# Android: (Camera2) Camera no longer alive exception after returning from an activity

Tags: android

I've been practicing with camera setup on android using `Camera2` API and `SurfaceView` for displaying a preview to the screen. However an exception is thrown when attempting to create a `CameraCaptureSession` after returning from a child activity which purpose is only to select a configuration for the camera.

The exception thrown is:

```
E/CameraCaptureSession: Session 0: Failed to create capture session; configuration failed
android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException: CAMERA_DISCONNECTED (2): createStream:632: Camera device no longer alive
```

This exception is thrown at the function when creating a capture session from the camera device, which looks like this:

```
private void startPreview() {
    try {
        final Surface previewSurface = this.cameraSurfaceView.getHolder().getSurface();
        List<Surface> targetSurfaces = Collections.singletonList(previewSurface);
        final CaptureRequest.Builder captureRequestBuilder = this.cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);

        captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(previewSurface);

        this.cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(targetSurfaces, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                try {
                    if (cameraDevice == null) {
                        return;
                    }

                    captureSession = session;

                    captureRequest = captureRequestBuilder.build();

                    session.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequest, null, cameraHandler);
                } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {

            }
        }, this.cameraHandler);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        final String message = "Unable to start preview";

        Log.e(TAG, message, e);
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

There is a catch to this exception so the app doesn't crash, however even with this exception, it seems like the new setting from the previous activity is working (At the moment it's just changing the camera id).

At first i thought it might be because i am not closing the resources when the new activity starts so this would not happen, so the function i created for that looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    if (this.captureSession != null) {
        try {
            this.captureSession.stopRepeating();
            this.captureSession.close();

            this.captureSession = null;
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    if (this.cameraDevice != null) {
        this.cameraDevice.close();

        this.cameraDevice = null;
    }

    this.cameraSurfaceView.getHolder()
        .getSurface()
        .release();
}
```

This is how the `SurfaceView` is being managed

```
@Override
protected void onInitialize() {
    this.cameraSurfaceView.getHolder()
        .addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Camera surface view created");

                initializeCamera();
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

            }
        });
}
```

But even this doesn't fix the error. I am concerned about this exception and i want to fix it.. i just don't know what else to do at this point. The code that executes the camera open comes from after having the `SurfaceView` available

Comment: Do you have a stale SurfaceView you're feeding to the camera session? Look at complete system logcat, to see what the camera service is complaining about.

Comment: @EddyTalvala I don't think i have, but i have added how the callback of the surface view is being handled